# Desktop not starting after Debian 10 upgrade

Tags: debian

Just upgraded a server box from an up-to-date Debian 9 to:

```
# uname -a
# Linux server 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now the graphics terminal only shows a blinking cursor post Grub menu. I can use tty1 to login and I can also RDP into the box and start a full desktop (LXDE).

The boot.log looks fine but in dmesg there are two long time gaps that caught my eye but I don't understand them:

```
[    2.829387] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   64.716171] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
[   64.747264] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=2 (0x14/0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line

...

[   81.114779] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[  238.774094] fuse init (API version 7.27)
[  238.900861] traps: light-locker[1097] trap int3 ip:7f8d014dec75 sp:7ffd5b5fdeb0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5800.3[7f8d014a6000+7e000]
```

Any idea where I could check next to find the issue?

Comment: The default display manager on Debian is **gdm**. Check the logs, to see why it didn't start: `journalctl -u gdm -e`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the tip, Piotr! That gave me more ideas. For LXDE I need to check for lighdm: `journalctl -u lightdm -e`

```
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Jan 21 18:19:16 server systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

The `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` let me to an Xserver issue in `/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log`

```
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jan 21 18:19:16 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

and more detailed in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[     3.799] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     3.799] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     3.800] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.800]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[     3.800]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.800]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     3.800] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     3.800] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     3.800] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.800]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[     3.800]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.800]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     3.800] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     3.800] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     3.800] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     3.800] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     3.800] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     3.800] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[     3.800] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     3.800] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     3.800] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     3.800] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.800]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     3.800]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     3.801] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[     3.801] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     3.801] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     3.801] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     3.801] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     3.801] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.801]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     3.801]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     3.801] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[     3.801] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     3.801] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     3.801] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     3.801] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     3.801] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     3.801] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     3.801] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[     3.801] (EE) 
[     3.801] (EE)
```

I found the busID using `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98
```

Than, I created the following `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to specify the busID. Now, everything is working.

```
Section "Device"

    Identifier "dev0"
    BusID "pci0:0:2:0:"

EndSection
```

I leave the accepted answer open, in case someone knows why the busID was not recognized by the system. I am happy to provide further input, if necessary.

Comment: In the end, I decided to run a clean install of Debian 10.2 since the problems from fixing the system seemed larger than the expected work from transferring the applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, my new install also has problems with the Intel UHD Graphics 630 adapter: https://superuser.com/questions/1519921/debian-buster-module-fbcon-not-found